# Is this post using WordPress Gallery?

Tags: images, gallery

Here's an interesting post that I saw toda - [check the gallery](http://thegloss.com/fashion/red-carpet-rundown-the-many-ugly-dresses-of-the-teen-choice-awards/gallery-page/2/)
This website is using WordPress, now if you notice the image URL changes however we can still see the javascript slide effect.

If it was a javascript slideshow then it shouldn't have changed the URL. This makes me think that how are they achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what they're using, but it's possible to change the URL in most modern browsers with JavaScript without refreshing the page and without using the hashtag, using the pushstate, popstate, and replacestate methods.

Comment: They are indeed using the replaceState method. The JS being used is here: http://cdn.b5media.com/hubs-v3/js/b5.js . Also, yes, the site is running WordPress.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Didn't know that we could achieve the same using JS